# Create Role Based Authorization in Auth0 and NextJS

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, auth0, higher-order-components

I created a nextjs web application with Auth0.

A user can login and logout. I can reach also user information. But I cannot see user roles.

I am getting the profile with Auth0's `getSession` method.

I want to create 2 different pages in NextJS which are for `user` and `admin` roles.

So it will be basic API authorization that I want. If a user is in `user` role then the user can access only the user page. If a user has `admin` role then the user can access all pages.

To I achive this I need to get user roles.The `getSession` method does not return the user roles.

How can solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: See https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/access-control/sample-use-cases-rules-with-authorization#add-user-roles-to-tokens for adding roles to profile response using Auth0 rules.

Comment: You can also see the instructions in this guide if the Auth0 docs are not available or unclear https://io.permit.io/auth0-integration

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you've figured it out by now, but I had the same question.

You have to explicitly add the roles to your tokens (Auth and id) if you want them attached to the user object.

You can do this multiple ways but I did this by adding a rule in Auth0:

```
function setRolesToUser(user, context, callback) {
  const namespace = 'http://my-website-name.com';
  const assignedRoles = (context.authorization || {}).roles;

  let idTokenClaims = context.idToken || {};
  let accessTokenClaims = context.accessToken || {};

  idTokenClaims[`${namespace}/roles`] = assignedRoles;
  accessTokenClaims[`${namespace}/roles`] = assignedRoles;

  context.idToken = idTokenClaims;
  context.accessToken = accessTokenClaims;

  callback(null, user, context);
}
```

Now your token(s) will have the rule attached as a namespaced array w/ the assigned roles in said array.

Now that your tokens have the roles attached you can use it to gate content on Nextjs like this:

```
import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
 
  const session = getSession(req, res);
  if (!session?.user['http://my-website-name/roles'].includes('admin')) {
    return { props: { error: 'Forbidden' } };
  } else {
    return {
      props: {},
    };
  }
}
```

Then in your component, you can return early like so:

```
if (error) return <div>{error}</div>;
```

This explains server side but you can do similar client-side w/ useUser:

```
import { useUser} from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
```

Comment: Hey mate! I am trying to assign roles at the time of sign up but unable to do so yet. I tried creating a Rule for this, but I'm not able to attach a parameter based on which I can decide whether the current user is an 'admin' or a 'user'. I tried using Scopes too, but it is still failing. I need to know how to attach a parameter on signup which can act as the decision factor. Can you please help me out? Thanks

Comment: Forgive my first reply, I misread what you were looking to do.  Unfortunately, I've not had a need to perform that function programmatically.  We wanted the admin to be able to manually control other admin users so the UI worked well for that scenario. 

Otherwise, I haven't looked into that functionality and don't know much.

Comment: No worries man! Thanks for responding

Comment: How would you do this using Actions?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to add rule in auth0 dashboard: https://auth0.com/docs/customize/rules. I wrote [a custom rule function in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377496/pass-parameters-into-auth0-sign-up/71432309#71432309)

Then write a HOC:

```
function withAuth<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
  return (role: string) => {
    return (props: T) => {
      // CUSTOM HOOK TO GET THE USER
      const { data, loading } = useGetUser();
      if (loading) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
      }

      if (!data) {
        return <Redirect to="/api/v1/login" />;
      } else {
        if (role && !isAuthorized(data, role)) {
          return <Redirect to="/api/v1/login" />;
        }

        return <Component user={data} loading={loading} {...props} />;
      }
    };
  };
}

export default withAuth;
```

isAuthorized:

```
import { Claims } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/session/session";
export const isAuthorized = (user: Claims, role: string) => {
  return (
    user &&
    // user[process.env.AUTH0_NAMESPACE + "/roles"] &&
    user["https://yourdomain.auth.com" + "/roles"].includes(role)
  );
};
```

useGetUser Hook

```
export const useGetUser = () => {
  // "/api/v1/me" is passed to fetcher as url
  const { data, error, ...rest } = useSWR("/api/v1/me", fetcher);
  return { data, error, loading: !data && !error, ...rest };
};
```

fetcher for useSWR

```
export const fetcher = (url: string) =>
  fetch(url).then(
    async (res: Response): Promise<any> => {
      const result = await res.json();

      if (res.status !== 200) {
        return Promise.reject(result);
      } else {
        return result;
      }
    }
  );
```

/api/v1/me api function in `pages`.

```
// you should already have set auth) instance
import auth0 from "@/utils/auth0";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async function me(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    await auth0.handleProfile(req, res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error in v1/me ", error);
    res.status(error.status || 400).end(error.message);
  }
}
```

After this set up you can wrap your components with `withAuth`

```
const Dashboard: React.FC<DashboardProps> = ({ user, loading }) => {
  return (
    <BaseLayout
    >
        <BasePage >
          {/* YOUR COMPONENT LOGIC HERE */}
        </BasePage>
    </BaseLayout>
  );
};

export default withAuth(Dashboard)("admin");
```