# Pass parameters into Auth0 sign up

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, auth0

I am using Auth0's provided login and sign-up screen (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nextjs/01-login#add-login-to-your-application) for my application. I set up a callback after signup where I create a profile in my DB with the email as the primary key.

The issue I'm running into is that on my home screen, I have a button that says "Sign up as admin" and another "Sign up as a user". **How do I pass into this Auth0 sign up screen whether the user click "user" or "admin" so that in the callback I can create the profile with "user" or "admin"?**

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `state` param to the `/authorize` request to maintain state between request and callback.

In Auth0, you if you need to discriminate between "user" or "admin", you could extract the state param specified the `/authorize` request from the context object (`context.request` to be specific) - see [here](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/context-object) for context object properties in Auth0 rules.

Answer (score 0):

You do not determine signup as admin or user on the front end, this is done in backend. In auth0 authentication you add [rules](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/rules) in auth) dashboard. When you sign in auth0, you can either select a rule template or you can create your own:

[image]

an example of script:

```
function (user, context, callback) {
  user.app_metadata = user.app_metadata || {};
  // You can add a Role based on what you want
  // In this case I check email
  //***** DETERMINE ADMINS HERE *******
  var addRolesToUser = function(user, cb) {
    if (user.email === "Email@email.com") {
      cb(null, ['admin']);
    } else {
      cb(null, ['guest']);
    }
  };

  addRolesToUser(user, function(err, roles) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
      user.app_metadata.roles = roles;
      auth0.users.updateAppMetadata(user.user_id, user.app_metadata)
        .then(function(){
          context.idToken[NAMESPACE] = user.app_metadata.roles;
          context.accessToken[NAMESPACE] = user.app_metadata.roles;
          callback(null, user, context);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
          callback(err);
        });
    }
  });
}
```